# thymeleaf Array index

Tags: arrays, spring, thymeleaf

I want to put a variable Between array's brackets [...] Like:

```html
th:value="${MyArray[${cmp.id}].checked}"
```

Here is my code

```html
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="cmp : ${allcomps}" > 

        <td><input type="checkbox" th:name="checkbox" th:checked="${cmp.checked}" th:value="${MyArray[0].checked}" /> </td>             

        <td th:text="${cmp.id}">Id</td>
        <td th:text="${cmp.l_fr}" >fr</td>
        <td th:text="${cmp.l_de}">de</td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave off the extra `${}`.  It should look like this:

```
th:value="${MyArray[cmp.id].checked}"
```